# Medium difficulty combinatorics problem with strange answer

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**(Brazil National Olympiad)**

*Let $n$ be a positive integer. In how many ways can we distribute $n+1$ toys to $n$ kids, such that each kid gets at least one toy?*

***My approach***:

For each child we can assign a number $k$ to it, representing  the toy it will get. So we have ${n + 1} \choose {n}$ choices for chosing the toys, then $n!$ ways to choose the assignment. Since we have already chosen the leftover toy (by chosing the ones who were not left over), we now only have to choose from $n$ children who's getting it. So the final answer should be:

$(n+1)!n$

But the answer is: $\frac{(n+1)!n}{2}$

**Can someone explain what was my mistake?**

Comment: I know, that's why i also choose the remainder toy (since the difference between toys and kids is 1), and later what child is going to get it.

Comment: The problem is that you counted each configuration twice: if you had given the leftover first, and the first as leftover, to the person who gets $2$, you would have the same configuration. Therefore you need to divide your result by $2$.

Comment: True Arnauld, i see it now, should've realized it. I also think there should be a way to solve without needing to divide or subtract combinations, i'll try to think of it.

Comment: Without dividing or subtracting, you can proceed as follows. First, choose which child gets 2 toys; there are $n$ options. Next choose which 2 toys to give this child; there are $\binom{n+1}2$ options. Finally, distribute the remaining $n-1$ toys among the remaining $n-1$ children, giving each child one toy; there are $(n-1)!$ options. So altogether, the number of options is $n\cdot\binom{n+1}2\cdot(n-1)!$. Simplify that and you get $(n+1)!\cdot\frac n2$.

Answer (score 2):

One may distribute toys in 3 steps:

1. [$n$ ways] Choose one kid of $n$;
2. [$\binom{n+1}{2}$ ways] Give him two of $n+1$ toys;
3. [$(n-1)!$ ways] Distribute remaining $n-1$ toys to $n-1$ kids (one toy to one kid). .

Multiplying counts of ways to perform each step we get $\frac{(n+1)!n}{2}$ ways at all, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

A standard combinatorial way to think about it would be to recognize the role of the [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). We proceed as follows:

(1) partition the set of $n+1$ toys into $n$ nonempty subsets. This is a Stirling number of the second kind ${n+1}\brace{n}$), which is here simply choosing two toys to group together (${{n+1}\brace{n}} = {{n+1}\choose{2}}$).  Then

(2) Bijectively assign the $n$ children to the $n$ elements of the partition in $n!$ factorial ways.

Moreover, this generalizes immediately to the problem:  How many ways are there to assign $m$ toys to $n$ children so that every child gets at least one toy? It's just ${{m}\brace{n}}n!$.

Comment: Really liked this solution, i´m really tempted to starting reading "Concrete Mathematics".

Comment: I've really enjoyed everything I've read of Knuth's.  His writing is fun, clear, and creative, and makes it genuinely fun to learn.  You can also find a pdf for free, so no harm in giving it a shot!